# Newly created folder with imaplib is hidden. How can I unhide it?

Tags: python, imaplib

I am using

```
strCreateYN, strCreateResponse = mail.create('INBOX.Foldername')
```

to create a folder. The folder gets created and I can move messages to it.
For some reason, the folder is hidden, and I have to go to the webmail client to unhide it.

Is there a way to change it to visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to follow up any create with a subscribe command, which some clients use to show "interesting" folders.

```
mail.subscribe('INBOX.Foldername')
```

Comment: This did it! Thank  you so much.

Comment: @AndyDelgado If the answer helped you, please up vote and accept the answer!  Cheers!